# Creating dialog with pointer in Android

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I want to create a dialog with a pointer which points to where the user has tapped. Something like what has been done in the native music app. I searched a lot, but don't know what exactly it is called, so i am attaching the screenshot of what I want to achieve.

[image]

Creating a dialog is easy, but how do I make it "point" dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should got for PoPUpWindow in android here is link for this..
http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/